# Regex. Up to six digits after separator but not all zeros

Tags: c#, regex

I need input in this form:

first digit ist always 0 
second is always . or , 
than up to six digits, but only digits not letters or other symbols
and not all zeros

```
private const string Pattern = @"^0(,|.)(?!0+$)+";

var regex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (!regex.IsMatch(inputToCheck))
{...}
```

This works ok for all the conditions except one with digits only.
This input should be disabled too: "0,01a", "0.01a1", "0,01a0"

How can I extend my regex pattern to this condition?

**Some examples of valid and invalid input.**

Valid: 
0,123456 
0,01 
0,010 
0,2

invalid: 
 
1,123456 
2,123456 
0,0 
0,00 
0,000 
a 
a,1 
0,01a 
0,01a1 
0,01a0

Comment: did you want 6 digits next to the comma or dot? Post some examples for valid and invalid matches.

Comment: What do you expect `(?!0+$)+` to do, and what else have you tried?

Comment: `.` is a [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in regex - you'll probably need to escape it

Comment: Are you trying to match a decimal number? it may be quicker to just test if the number is the same as one rounded to 6 decimal places

Comment: so the string you're going to match must contain 8 chars, where last 6 chars must be digits but not of only zero's. Am i correct?

Comment: Try this `^0[\.,][1-9]{6}$` https://regex101.com/r/pB1zQ7/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I have updated my questions with some examples

Comment: @AvinashRaj "so the string you're going to match must contain 8 chars, where last 6 chars must be digits but not of only zero's. Am i correct?" - yes you are right. Its not necessary last 6 but up to 6. It can be for example 4 or 3.

Comment: did you want to match `0.` ? because zero digits at the last.

Comment: @AvinashRaj what do you mean under "late update"? I try to update as soon as I can.

Comment: ok, did you want to match also `0.`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the answer from mroemore helped me. This one: "^0[,\.](?!0*$)[\d]{1,6}$". To your question: I need 0 at the first place, after it . or ,

Comment: @AvinashRaj why have you deleted you post? You answer with "^0[.,](?!0+$)\d{1,6}$" works too. I wanted to upvote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Here's my solution to this:

```
^0[,.](?!0+$)\d{1,6}$
```

This will make sure that the first digit is zero. It then checks that the next character is either a comma or a dot. Then, using a lookahead it ensures that the rest of the subject string is not entirely zeros. If this passes, it checks that the remaining characters are all digits.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes it is, but your one with "^0[.,](?!0+$)\d{1,6}$" was also correct.

Comment: @mroemore i suggest you to change `0*$` to `0+$`, since there must be a digit present just after to dot or comma. And also non need for a character class.

Comment: awesome @mroemore the negative lookahead saved my day

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^0[.,][1-9]{0,6}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Of course this regex don't allow `0` after the `,` or `.`. If you want to allow `0` but restrict ending by `0` you can do:

```
^0[.,][0-9]{0,5}[1-9]$
```

And also you can shorten it a little to:

```
^0[.,]\d{0,5}[1-9]$
```

Comment: You may want to escape the `.`

Comment: Thank you for your response +1. Its not work for this input "0,010"

Comment: This does not check if the final digits are not all zeros.

Comment: @CoderofCode you sure? I think within a character class is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  expression

```
^^0(,|.)([0-9]{1,4}$)+
```

Comment: @MikroDel is this helpful for you ?

Comment: @Thank you for you response. This doent work for 0,01  0,123456  0,010 0,2

Comment: @MikroDel i thought only 6 chars

have looke to my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be using regex to parse numbers, you can do it by just validating it as a number as so..

```
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    string[] inputs = new string[]{"0,123456",
                                    "0,01",
                                    "1,123456",
                                    "0,0"};
    foreach(var input in inputs)
    {
    double val;
    if(Double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Number, culture, out val) 
        && Math.Round(val, 6) == val
        && val != 0.0
        && (int)val == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is valid", input);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is invalid", input);
    }
```

Output

> 0,123456 is valid
>
> 0,01 is valid
>
> 1,123456 is invalid
>
> 0,0 is invalid

[IDEOne example](https://ideone.com/ilXcB3)